# Compare XML file name using script task

Tags: ssis

> Can  anyone  tell  me  how can i compare file name of the XML file

to the file names stored in a database table.

Here i want to try script task of ssis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Foreach Loop Container with the enumerator type set to "Foreach File Enumerator".  Configure the control to point to the folder / file types you are interested in pulling out the file name as a variable.

Within the Foreach Loop Container drop in a Execute SQL Task and pass the file name to a stored proc with something  like

```
SELECT top 1 id
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  FieldName = @PassedInFileName
```

If you have a row returned from the proc, the file exists